# Zombie window in C++ software writen on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, makefile

I wrote a C++ software using GTK2 library for UI.

It'a simple software that analyze a map coded on XML file to calculate the shortest path between two points and draw it on the image (I'm using `Cairo` library for this).

The compilation (with makefile) gave no errors but when I execute the program the window appears empty.If I try to compile with debug option (-g) and execute the program with ddd for debugging it returnS "no debugging symbols found".

makefile is

```
CXXFLAGS += -Wall `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
ObjectsMy = main.o interface.o callback.o map.o path.o draw.o
NaViGaToR: DependenciesMy $(ObjectsMy)
   g++ -g $(ObjectsMy) -o NaViGaToR `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags --libs`
DependenciesMy: 
   g++ -MM main.cpp interface.cpp callback.cpp map.cpp path.cpp draw.cpp
           > DependenciesMy
-include DependenciesMy
.PHONY: clean cleanall
clean:
   rm $(ObjectsMy) DependenciesMy
   rm $ map.png
cleanall:
   rm $(ObjectsMy) NaViGaToR DependenciesMy
   rm $ map.png
```

Can you see some error in this?

Comment: What do you expect? It's not really clear what your question is. That said, `rm $` seems wrong, unless make is somehow replacing this. BTW: If you have problems with the C++ code, you might want to include a minimal example in your question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `-g` to the linker and not to the compiler. If there's no debugging info in the object files there won't be any in the executable. You need to add `-g` to the `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Sorry for my question so general but with -g option into CXXFLAGS i can debug my program!!!